# Hasse diagram question about relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

I have the following Hasse diagram below, the question is given specific generalised quantifiers I have to list the subsets of {a,b,c,d} which the quantifier corresponds to.

I have completed the question and would like to check if my answers make sense.

```
Generalised quantifier                                subsets
1. Every {b,c}                                    bc,abc,bcd,abcd
2. At least two {a,b,c}                      abc,ab,ac,bc,abd,acd,bcd,abcd
3. Fewer than two {a,b,c,d}                   a,b,c,d, {}  <- empty set
4. At most two {b,d}                        bd,b,d,cd,bc,ad,ab,abc,acd,abcd, {}
5. Exactly two {a,b,c}                      ab,bc,ac,abd,acd,bcd
6. Some but not all {d,a,c}                 d,a,c,acd,ac,ad,ab,bd,bc
7. Ic                                       c
8. Exactly as many {a,b,c} as {b,d}         b
9. Id *OR* NO {c,b}                         d,ad
10. Ic *AND* NOT Id                         c,ac,bc,abc
```

I am not too sure about 6,7,8,9 and 10. Regarding question 6 I understand it as a proper subset of {a,b,c,d} when comparing it with {d,a,c}.

Questions 7, 9 and 10, symbol I is as far as I understand an Identity relation (could not find much on this except that its basically just itself? as in Id would return a subset of just {d}). In saying that 9 and 10 then contradict to my understanding of it and are most likely incorrect.

Finally for question 4 I added the empty set {} because the question asks "at most two" so I figured it could be (nothing, some combination or single element of the subset given)

Some background on generalised quantifiers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_quantifier

Thank you
[image]

Comment: It is considered rude to delete your question after recieving an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I’m interpreting everything correctly, $1,2,3$, and $5$ are correct.

$4$ is not: the set $\{b,d\}$ has only two elements, so every subset of $\{a,b,c,d\}$ contains at most two elements from $\{b,d\}$. Thus, you’re missing $a,c,ac,abd$, and $bcd$.

$6$ is also wrong: you should not have $acd$, as it has all three of $d,a$, and $c$. The only sets that you may not have are $\{\},b,acd$, and $abcd$, so the correct list is: $a,c,d,ac$, $ad,cd,ab,bc,bd,abc,abd,bcd$.

$7$ is correct if your understanding of $I$ is correct.

In $8$ you’ve missed quite a few possibilities: $\{\}$ has $0$ from each of $\{a,b,c\}$ and $\{b,d\}$; $ad$ and $cd$, as well as $b$, have one from each of those sets; and $abd$ and $bcd$ have $2$ from each of those sets.

You’ve also missed several in $9$: if $\text{NO }\{c,d\}$ means ‘nothing from the set $\{c,d\}$’, the list should also include $a$ and $\{\}$. (Here again I’m assuming that your interpretation of $I$ is correct.)

Finally, the only subset of $\{a,b,c,d\}$ that is both identical to $\{c\}$ and not identical to $\{d\}$ is $\{c\}$, so the only correct item on your list is $c$.

Comment: That makes sense, I will have to re-write the question on paper now as I see there are quite a few mistakes. Thank you for clearing it up. (P.S. I am not 100% convinced on the Identity relation but I guess I will just leave it as is and let the grades show if I understood it or not)

Comment: @SayfT: You’re welcome. (I have to admit that I can’t shed any better light on $I$: this is not something that I’ve seen in this form before.)

Comment: @BrianMScott Neither have I, I guess it's a "let's just wing it and see" type of situation now hah